# how to apply y = mx + b formula in python in order to get my regression line?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been learning machine learning in python and currently im studying the basics. Im now studying linear regression and trying to implement some mathematical formulas into python code. I managed to write the basic formulas successfuly but now I want to get the line in my graph which goes through my X means and Y means

I tried to look up the web but every explanation was using predictions, x_train, y_train ect. which I heard about but I havent gotten there yet.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X_positions = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])
y_positions = np.array([4,5,6,5,7])
plt.plot([X_positions], [y_positions], 'ro')
plt.axis([0,10,0,10])

X_means = X_positions.mean()
y_means = y_positions.mean()
plt.plot([X_means], [y_means], 'go')
plt.axis([0,10,0,10])

X_minus_X_means = X_positions - X_means
y_minus_y_means = y_positions - y_means
X_minus_X_means_squared = X_minus_X_means**2
X_minus_X_means_times_y_minus_y_means = X_minus_X_means * y_minus_y_means

m = sum(X_minus_X_means_times_y_minus_y_means) / sum(X_minus_X_means_squared)
b = y_means - m * X_means
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? Are you trying to get the graph of your line?

Comment: no, im trying to get the line in my graph which goes through my (X means, y means)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at this [this tutorial](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.01-simple-line-plots.html), since I stole a few lines from it.

First, you need to construct an array of x-values:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 11) # constructs a numpy array of [0.0, 1.0, ... 10.0]
```

Then, you plot a your function:

```
plt.plot(x, m*x+b, linestyle='solid')
```

x is your numpy array, m is your calculated slope, b is your calculated y-intercept

To show your graph, do:

```
plt.show()
```

To save your plot, do:

```
plt.savefig("myplot.png")
```

In the context of your program:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X_positions = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])
y_positions = np.array([4,5,6,5,7])
plt.plot([X_positions], [y_positions], 'ro')
plt.axis([0,10,0,10])

X_means = X_positions.mean()
y_means = y_positions.mean()
plt.plot([X_means], [y_means], 'go')
plt.axis([0,10,0,10])

X_minus_X_means = X_positions - X_means
y_minus_y_means = y_positions - y_means
X_minus_X_means_squared = X_minus_X_means**2
X_minus_X_means_times_y_minus_y_means = X_minus_X_means * y_minus_y_means

m = sum(X_minus_X_means_times_y_minus_y_means) / sum(X_minus_X_means_squared)
b = y_means - m * X_means

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10) # constructs a numpy array of [0.0, 1.0, ... 10.0]
plt.plot(x, m*x+b, linestyle='solid') 
plt.show() # or use plt.savefig("filename.png")
```